# Time series of car acceleration?

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons

Study: Time series with 10 different timepoints, 10 different speeds for 4 different cars. I want to test if there are statistical differences between the accelerations of the cars. Can anybody tell me which test i should do using Prism (GraphPad) ?